# Jquery auto json to name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have problem with my function:

```
function jsonToName(j){
  try {

      var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( j );

      $.each(obj,function(z,x){
        // if(jQuery.isPlainObject(x)){
        if( (typeof x === "object") && (x !== null) ){

          jsonToName(x);
        }else{
          $('[name="'+z+'"]').val(x);
        }
      });

  }
  catch (err) {
//error
  }
}
```

I have many of field text, select etc. and I need to parse json to them values, but some times input value is object, array or json and I don't know how to convert this values.

```
{
  "id": 13,
  "packages_id": 4,
  "packages_price_id": 1,
  "numer": "D4X9nU",
  "property_types_id": null,
  "user_id": 1,
  "transaction_type": 1,
  "property_type": 2,
  "price": null,
  "plot_additional": null,
  "house_additional":"{\"aaa\":\"on\"}",
  "commercial_additional": "",
  "highlight_order": [],
  "renew": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "property_id": 13,
      "order_date": "2018-02-11T13:59:59+01:00",
      "pay": false,
      "price": 59,
      "paymentKey": "GdUZ7gM1jMCKSaa61stNEmzAK9AHRoFHfA2",
      "banners_price": null
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see, I have a renew value (object) and house_additional (string json).
I try to do recursive function but it not works. My fields name is for example:

```
<input name="numer" >
<input name="house_additional[aaa]" >
<input name="renew[pay]" >
<input name="some[some2][some3][some4][some5]" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery, and I'm not sure why you are parsing this JSON other than 1 pair of quotes that need removing - other than that it's a valid object that does not need parsing. Below you'll find a terrible hack to fill in your input values - can you change your input names instead?  Or maybe use data attributes? While this works for your first 3 inputs ('some' is not in your JSON, I assume you want any nested other values to work there) - but overall this is not a great way to do this - if you have to go to this much trouble to match your values, your architecture usually needs re-thinking!

```js
var j = 
{
  "id": 13,
  "packages_id": 4,
  "packages_price_id": 1,
  "numer": "D4X9nU",
  "property_types_id": null,
  "user_id": 1,
  "transaction_type": 1,
  "property_type": 2,
  "price": null,
  "plot_additional": null,
  "house_additional":{"aaa":"on"},
  "commercial_additional": "",
  "highlight_order": [],
  "renew": [
    {
      "id": 15,
      "property_id": 13,
      "order_date": "2018-02-11T13:59:59+01:00",
      "pay": false,
      "price": 59,
      "paymentKey": "GdUZ7gM1jMCKSaa61stNEmzAK9AHRoFHfA2",
      "banners_price": null
    }
  ]
}

jsonToName(j);

function jsonToName(j){
  var obj = j;
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0; i < inputs.length;i++) {
    console.log('running loop '+i)
    var name = inputs[i].name;
    name = name.replace(/]/g,'');
    console.log('name is '+name)
    var names = name.split('[')
    var first = names[0]
    var second = names[1]
      if (j[first] && j[first][second]) {
        inputs[i].value = j[first][second]
      }
        if (j[first] && !j[first][second]) {
        inputs[i].value = j[first]
      }    
        if (j[first] && j[first][0] && !j[first][second] && j[first][0][second] != undefined) {
        inputs[i].value = j[first][0][second]
      }          
  } // end loop
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="numer" >
<input name="house_additional[aaa]" >
<input name="renew[pay]" >
<input name="some[some2][some3][some4][some5]" >
```